# Empty sets and characteristic functions

Tags: analysis, soft-question, real-numbers, infinity

The sequence of functions $g_n=gX_{\{g>n\}}(x)$ converges to $gX_{\{g>\infty\}}$ as $n$ $\longrightarrow$ $\infty$. The set $\{g>\infty\}$ is equal to $\emptyset$ or to the set $\{g=\infty\}$?

Does the set $\{g>\infty\}$ make sense(in general)?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your notation. What is $g_1$ for example? If $n = 1$ then $g_1 = gX_{\{g>1\}}(x)$. What does that mean? What id $g$? If $\{g > 1\}$ is a set, what is the $g$ we're multiplying the characteristic function by?

Comment: ${g>1}=\{x:g(x)>1\}$ , $g:$ $ \mathbb{R}$ $\longrightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: $g$ is arbitrary?

Comment: yes it can be any function.The convergence does not depend on g

Comment: or for convinience take g=x

Comment: Looks like the $g_n$'s always converge to the zero function, is that right? The notation $\{g > \infty\}$ is just the empty set, and its char function is the zero function.